# 100% DIV height in TD with custom scroll

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

i realy confused with this template:

```css
/* slider
/* -------------------------------------------------- */
.slider {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  background: #ffffff;  
}
.slider__in {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.slider__row {
  display: table-row;
}
.slider__row_type_flex {
  height: 100%;
}
.slider__cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.slider__row_type_flex .slider__cell {
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.slider__cell-out {
  height: 100%;  
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.slider__cell-in {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
/* chat
/* -------------------------------------------------- */
.chat {
  width: 300px;
  font: 13px / 18px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}
.chat-header {
  background: lightslategrey;
  height: 50px;  
}
.chat-body {
  height: 100%;
  background: whitesmoke;
}
.chat-footer {
  height: 150px;
  background: navajowhite;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider chat" id="chat">
  <div class="slider__in">
    <div class="slider__row">
      <div class="slider__cell chat-header">
        Liquid height header with some text
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__row">
      <div class="slider__cell chat-body">
        <div class="slider__cell-out">
          <div class="slider__cell-in">
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
            <p>Liquid height content with custom scroll if it overfow cell height</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slider__row">
      <div class="slider__cell chat-footer">
        Fixed height footer always here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need center cell stretch to all free space of 100% table and inside this scrollable content with custom scroll.
It works great but IE 10 and lower makes middle row 100% and push out footer

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your expected result with the following change.
I have given the JSFiddle link too for your reference.

[MIDDLE ROW STRETCH COMPLETELY](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lcqae8f/)

I just removed the **vertical-align: top;** in the CSS part.

```
.slider__cell {
   display: table-cell;
}
```